# parameters to Ellipses in C++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Is it possible to pass parameters of different types in Ellipses(...)? I am writing a function to make the SQL query, where I want to add values to the Insert statement through Ellipse and my values are of different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a word of warning, don't be too clever with this. Not that I've suffered greatly for similar endeavors.  :))

Sqlite has built in query builders, check those first.  What they wont let you do is specify a table name, which is probably what your problem is.

[boost::format](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format&rct=j&q=boost%20format&ei=XLwcTpuaAefd0QHwxfzIBw&usg=AFQjCNEwZlA1fNRDBci115CtvhIKbSGY3A&sig2=G5FsMFPYh8pxmQtzLGQvlw&cad=rja) is a good option for this.  It's type safe and less likely to segfault on you like C's variadic arguments.

```
std::string statement = boost::str( 
    boost::format("SELECT tab.* FROM %1% as tab")
        % "my_table_name"
  );
```

EDIT:

Sqlite handles parameter binding on its own, you shouldn't need any variadic aruments for that.

The [sqlite3_bind_* functions](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) provide access.

You might use something like this:

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO tab (a,b) VALUES (?1,?2);";
// create statement
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, 43);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, 40000);
```

These bind functions have return values which you must check, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My problem is to specify values for the SQL table column, while I have only one table, so I do not have problems with that. 
Specifically, I'm looking for something to help me in following:
Insert into Values(value1, value2, value3); 

how do I write a function to take any number and any type of values?

Comment: @ddama updated the answer with an untested example, check full docs for caveats.

Comment: @ddama:  I have created a record & field system that can generate SQL statements for insert.  A record is a vector of pointers to a Field base class.  Creating the SQL INSERT statement is a matter of iterating over the vector, asking each field for its name.  This technique will allow you to have different value types in your table.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You'd need some mechanism for determining the number and types of the parameters (such as `printf`'s format string).